# Django - Returning full exception trace to front-end on a 400

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

So just for closed beta and internal testing purposes I'm trying to return the exception with the 400 error in my Django server. Here is an example below of how I am doing this in Django code. I have a partner working on the front-end and they said they can't get the error out of the 400 response. I assumed it'd be in like `response.body['error']`. How can I send back a 400 with the full error trace in a way that can be pulled out by the front-end?

```
except Exception as e:
    return Response(dict(error=str(e),
                         user_message=error_message_generic),
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach is this:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest

return HttpResponseBadRequest(JsonResponse({
    "error": "Malformed request",
    # Any other fields you'd want
}))
```

See more at official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseBadRequest).

If you are interested on returning specifically a traceback of your back-end exception, you can go this way:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
import traceback

...
except Exception as e:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest(JsonResponse({
        "error": "Malformed request",
        "traceback": traceback.format_exc()
    }))

traceback.format_exc()
```

But it's not the best way to do it in all cases. If you are sure, that exception is related to user's input, then traceback wouldn't be so helpful for user. You should better use Serializer, whose validation would be much better. If you're just delivering information about unknown error I'd advise to use `HttpResponseServerError` and log your exceptions anywhere, to [sentry](https://sentry.io/for/python/), for example.

Comment: interesting. Is what I'm not going to return anything? I don't know if I did anything wrong or my partner just isn't looking at the wrong part of the response.

Comment: @user8714896 added some details. Works for you now?